# Is it possible to integrate a WYSIWYG Editor into a form?

Tags: forms, editor, wysiwyg

The site I'm trying to build will allow users to use a wysiwyg editor to format text to how they like it. I would like to try and retrieve this formatted text through a form. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. [Read this.](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it could be done programatically by parsing the form from the editor to strip the HTML tags, then reconstructing the HTML when retrieving the information.

Very brief/simplified explanation aside, you can simply use an already existing editor to do this for you, without writing custom code. Take a look at [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).